# Instance of Webriver take much time to load

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to minimize the duration of loading WebDriver instance.
[image]

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("test-type");
            capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<Path to binary>");
            capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver   driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: simple answer no. possible solution..use fast machine..or run ur tests on the same browser instance once launched

Comment: Use an SSD hard drive, disable the virtual memory and disable the antivirus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check your network connectivity. Because it would not take much time to load the webdriver instance.

Thanks and Regards,
Karthik